# how to fix locale issues in centos 6

Tags: linux, centos6, localization

I have a centos 6 server and I am running into some locale issues. When  I type the command `locale`, it gives

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.utf8"
LC_TIME="en_US.utf8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.utf8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.utf8"
LC_NAME="en_US.utf8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.utf8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.utf8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.utf8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have following in my environment file:

```
$ more /etc/environment
LANG=en_US.utf8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8
```

Also /etc/locale.conf has following:

```
$ more /etc/locale.conf
LANG=en_US.UTF8
```

Why it is still saying:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/etc/sysconfig/i18n`

I have the following in the file:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

Comment: It is already there... but still not working.